# Inconsistent Behaviour for Fluent NHibernate Reference Mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I've been using Fluent NHibernate and I've noticed what I think is inconsistent behaviour when using reference when overloading the default Foreign Key convention.

Following the conventions of NHibernate, I would have a foreign key name with a `_` within it and a single record set in each one with a foreign key relationship between the records. For example:

```
Person
Id - Integer - PK
Name - String/NVarchar

Address
Id - Integer - PK
LineOne - String/NVarchar
Person_Id - Integer - FK
```

With the following code, this all works as expected

```cs
void Main()
{
    using var factory = Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(MsSqliteConfiguration.Standard.UsingFile("C:\\Temp\\Test.db"))
        .Mappings(mappings =>
        {
            mappings
                .FluentMappings
                .AddFromAssemblyOf<AddressClassMap>();
        })
        .BuildSessionFactory();
    using var session = factory.OpenSession();
    
    session.Query<Address>().ToList().Dump();
}

public class PersonClassMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
    public PersonClassMap()
    {
        Table("Person");
        
        Id(x => x.Id);
    }
}

public class AddressClassMap : ClassMap<Address>
{
    public AddressClassMap()
    {
        Table("Address");

        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.PersonId).Column("Person_Id");
        
        References(x => x.Person).Not.LazyLoad();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        
    public virtual int PersonId { get; set; }
    
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Will return the expected data:

[image]

However, if I don't follow convention and have no underscore, like so:

```
Person
Id - Integer - PK
Name - String/NVarchar

Address
Id - Integer - PK
LineOne - String/NVarchar
PersonId - Integer - FK
```

I would expect, adding a convention for the foreign key like in the below code, would have the same effect but just would work without the underscore:

```cs
void Main()
{
    using var factory = Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(MsSqliteConfiguration.Standard.UsingFile("C:\\Temp\\Test.db"))
        .Mappings(mappings =>
        {
            mappings
                .FluentMappings
                .AddFromAssemblyOf<AddressClassMap>()
                .Conventions.Add(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Helpers.ForeignKey.EndsWith("Id"));
        })
        .BuildSessionFactory();
    using var session = factory.OpenSession();
    
    session.Query<Address>().ToList().Dump();
}

public class PersonClassMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
    public PersonClassMap()
    {
        Table("Person");
        
        Id(x => x.Id);
    }
}

public class AddressClassMap : ClassMap<Address>
{
    public AddressClassMap()
    {
        Table("Address");

        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.PersonId);
        
        References(x => x.Person).Not.LazyLoad();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        
    public virtual int PersonId { get; set; }
    
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

However this would yield a exception:

[image]

I would expect that this code would allow me to not have to follow the convention of using '_' but this doesn't seem to be the case without hitting the exception. I would expect in the first example, it should be working the same way as the second.

The behavior I desire would be to have the code be like the first example I gave, but not have to follow the convention of NHibernate. This would enable me to have the foreign key ID set on the entity and allow me to persist the relationship using this foreign key property.

I'm unsure if I may have done something wrong or missed something? I've tried various other options of propertyref, etc, to see if it would yield the behaviour I would expect but no avail so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work as expected in first example. It creates 2 columns in `Address` table for person:

1. `PersonId` for `References(x => x.Person)`
2. `Person_Id` for `Map(x => x.PersonId).Column("Person_Id")`)

In second example you are trying to map the same column multiple times hence the exception. NHibernate doesn't know how to build INSERT/UPDATE statements for duplicate columns. You need to mark duplicates as read-only properties (as `insert="false" update="false"` in xml mapping). Something like:

```
Map(x => x.PersonId);
References(x => x.Person).Not.LazyLoad().ReadOnly();
```